# Find duplicates in a One to Many table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very simple table:

```
create table #Person_Tasks( Person_ID int, Task_ID int)
```

I like to find all people that worked on the EXACT same tasks. For instance, P1 worked on T1 and T2. How can I find all the other people that ONLY worked on T1 and T2?

Here is some sample data:

```
insert into #Person_Tasks
values
(0,0),
(0,1),
(0,2),
(1,0),
(1,1),
(1,3),
(2,0),
(2,1),
(2,2)
```

In this example only P0 and P2 have the exact same tasks. P1 has the same number of tasks but one task doesn't match the other people's task ID.

The table is quite big with 1000s of people and 100Ks of Tasks.

Comment: can you be more specific? how many tasks can a given person have? how many overlaps would be considered a match?

Comment: How about some usable sample data?

Comment: What you are asking is called relational division. Here is [a good article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) that explains various forms and includes examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method, assuming that the rows are unique:

```
with pt as (
      select pt.*, count(*) over (partition by person_id) as num_tasks
      from person_tasks pt
     )
select pt.person_id, pt2.person_id
from pt left join
     pt pt2
     on pt2.task_id = pt.task_id and pt.person_id <> pt2.person_id
group by pt.person_id, pt2.person_id, pt.num_tasks, pt2.num_tasks
having (count(*) = pt.num_tasks and pt.num_tasks = pt2.num_tasks) or
       pt2.person_id is null
```

This does a self join and then counts the number of matches for each pair.  If all the counts match, then the two people have the same tasks.

Here is a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d62d31e3b571ee186ddcd50ff6f44eeb) showing it working.

Comment: I think there are some syntax errors. It should be "with pt as (". Why is there "select pt.*"? Does "pt" exist?

Comment: A few more corrections: with pt as (
      select pt.*, count(*) over (partition by person_id) as num_tasks
      from #Person_Tasks pt
     )
select pt.person_id, pt2.person_id
from pt left join
     pt pt2
     on pt2.task_id = pt.task_id
group by pt.person_id, pt2.person_id
having count(*) = pt.num_tasks and pt.num_tasks = pt2.num_tasks;

Comment: Still some errors: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 106
Column 'pt.num_tasks' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 106
Column 'pt.num_tasks' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 106
Column 'pt.num_tasks' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @chhenning . . . A tested and validated version is now in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample, this will work as well :

```
SELECT Person_ID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    COUNT(Task_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Person_ID) cnt
    FROM Person_Tasks
    WHERE 
        Task_ID IN(1,2)
) D 
WHERE 
    cnt > 1
GROUP BY Person_ID
```